# how to split set values and Insert each row in Trigger PL/SQL?

Tags: mysql, plsql, triggers

i have one order table. i need **before inserting** order table, create and using **triggers insert** given below format.

**example:** 

 
question:

id   value 
 1   2,5,8

answer:

id   value 
 1   2
 1   5
 1   8

Comment: A bit confusing question. Do you want to make "insert into my_table values (1, '2,5,8')" and get logic like "insert into my_table values (1, '2'); insert into my_table values (1, '5'); insert into my_table values (1, '8')"?

Comment: yes.i want this but using triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers in Oracle have mode "INSTEAD OF" which is exactly what you need, but the problem is that you can't use "INSTEAD OF" trigger on a simple table, it's only available for views. So the only option I see for you is to wrap your table in a view. For example you have a table:

```
create table my_table(c_id number, c_value varchar2(5))
```

Rename it and create view with old table' name:

```
rename my_table to my_table_old;

create view my_table as select * from my_table_old;
```

All existing queries to my_table should work with this view, including updates and deletes. Now we can create INSTEAD OF trigger:

```
create or replace trigger t_my_table
instead of insert on my_table
for each row
declare
  qid number;
begin
  insert into my_table_old
  select :new.c_id, regexp_substr (:new.c_value, '[^,]+', 1, level) as part
  from dual  
  connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (:new.c_value, '[^,]+'))  + 1;
end;
```

This hierarchial query will turn comma-separated string into a table with single value in a row.

OK, let's check if it works:

```
SQL> insert into my_table values (1, '2,5,8');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from my_table;

      C_ID C_VALUE
---------- ---------------
         1 2
         1 5
         1 8
```

Simple single-value insert will also work:

```
SQL> insert into my_table values (2, '100');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from my_table;

      C_ID C_VALUE
---------- ---------------
         1 2
         1 5
         1 8
         2 100
```

Note that using of trigger will affect performance of insert queries for a bit.

Comment: i got this error.#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'trigger t_my_table
instead of insert on my_table
for each row
declare
  qid ' at line 1

Comment: With the `oracle` tag in your question, you have to expect `oracle` answers. ;-)

Comment: Not aware about triggers in MySQL, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can amend the regex to suit your exact requirements but the following performs effectively as per your question:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XX_ORDER_TRG 
BEFORE INSERT ON XX_ORDER_TBL
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 

l_num1 NUMBER;
l_num2 NUMBER;
l_num3 NUMBER;

BEGIN

/* If the whole string in value matches 3 single digits separated by commas */
IF  REGEXP_LIKE(:new.value,'^(\d{1},\d{1},\d{1})$') THEN
    /* Split the value into its 3 separate digits - Capture Groups are not supported natively*/
    l_num1 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(:new.value,'\d{1}',1,1);
    l_num2 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(:new.value,'\d{1}',1,2);
    l_num3 := REGEXP_SUBSTR(:new.value,'\d{1}',1,3);

    :new.value := l_num1;
    INSERT INTO XX_TBL (id, value) VALUES (:new.id, l_num2);
    INSERT INTO XX_TBL (id, value) VALUES (:new.id, l_num3);

END IF;           


END;
```

Comment: INSERT INTO my_table values (1, '2,5,8')  and get TRIGGERS INSERT logic like "insert into my_table values (1, '2'); insert into my_table values (1, '5'); insert into my_table values (1, '8')"